# Second Baire class and Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category

I am new to Baire class theory, but need it for one part of a project I am working on. I have seen it referenced that functions of second Baire class are Borel measurable. For example here in this [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=BMWk0X8rl_YC&pg=PA256&lpg=PA256&dq=second%20baire%20class%20function%20is%20borel%20measurable&source=bl&ots=SH-MzID-Qe&sig=D7snfK0mf8HnsfeGhzMqr1t6uyw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBmoVChMImP2Zj5qsxwIVSjQ-Ch1MhQae#v=onepage&q=second%20baire%20class%20function%20is%20borel%20measurable&f=false), but I cannot find a proof of this (or have come accross one and not realized I am looking at it).

My other question, regarding this same result, is what what restrictions are there on the domain? For example, if we have a function $f:B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $B$ is a Borel measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or any metric space and $f$ is of second Baire class on $B$. Does it follow that $f$ is Borel measurable?

Comment: Any pointwise limit of Borel measurable functions is Borel measurable.  It follows that functions of *any* Baire class are Borel measurable.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks :) That answers my second question too I think.

Answer (score 1):

Converting comment to an answer:

Any pointwise limit of Borel measurable functions is Borel measurable. It follows that functions of any Baire class are Borel measurable.